# Constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const CurlHandle'

Tags: c++, json, oop, stl

In the following code, I am getting an error and warning on the line `constexpr static auto f = [](CURL* c)` in private section of class.

> Constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const CurlHandle::(lambda at /alienware/CLionProjects/Bitcoin/main.cpp:48:31)' lambda closure types are non-literal types before C++17

```
    class CurlHandle {
private :
    CURL_ptr curlptr;
    std::string data;
    std::array<char, CURL_ERROR_SIZE> errorBuffer;
    constexpr static auto f = [](CURL* c) {
        curl_easy_cleanup(c);
        curl_global_cleanup();

};

public :
    CurlHandle() : curlptr(curl_easy_init(), f) {
        CURLcode code = CURLE_OK;

        code = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        if (code != CURLE_OK){
            throw CurlException(static_cast<int>(code), "Unable to global init");
        }

        curl_easy_setopt(curlptr.get(), CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, &errorBuffer[0]);
        if (code != CURLE_OK){
            throw CurlException(static_cast<int>(code), "Unable to set error buffer");
        }
        curl_easy_setopt(curlptr.get(), CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, dataHandler);
        if (code != CURLE_OK){
            throw CurlException(static_cast<int>(code), std::string(&errorBuffer[0]));
        }

        curl_easy_setopt(curlptr.get(), CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
        if (code != CURLE_OK){
            throw CurlException(static_cast<int>(code), std::string(&errorBuffer[0]));
        }
    }

    void setUrl(const std::string& url) {
        CURLcode code = curl_easy_setopt(curlptr.get(), CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        if (code != CURLE_OK){
            throw CurlException(static_cast<int>(code), std::string(&errorBuffer[0]));
        }

    }

    void fetch() {
        data.empty();
        CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curlptr.get());
        if (code != CURLE_OK){
            throw CurlException(static_cast<int>(code), std::string(&errorBuffer[0]));
        }
    }

    const std::string& getFetchedData() const {
        return data;
    }
};
```

I am not able to compile the code. I don't understand what's going on?

Comment: Do you want to use libcurl at compile time? I can understand this would be useful but unfortunately C++ guys probably will never accept the idea of even giving you access to local filesystem at compile time...

Comment: So, how exactly do I use `libcurl` at compile time? Is there any way to do it on Linux or Windows?

Comment: See here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression . Mainly this part : "A core constant expression is any expression whose evaluation would not evaluate any one of the following: " [...] " (until C++17) a lambda expression "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the following example:

```
constexpr auto f = []() {};

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the type of the `constexpr` variable `f` is `const<lambda()>`. The compiler complains about `<lambda()>` not being literal, because it's a [closure type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), and closure types are only literal from C++17 on.

Now, you can try this with C++17 and see if you can use `libcurl` at compile-time, but I'll consider this out of scope. Keep in mind that the `constexpr` specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)). So, if you use some variable or function, which cannot be evaluated at compile time, in a lambda, then that lambda cannot be evaluated at compile time either, and therefore cannot be `constexpr`.

Comment: It does not work in C++ 17 as well. I am not getting how to make this lambda function return literal type. Is there any way other than using constexpr?

Comment: It's not working because your CURL* is not a literal type. Why do you need to be it constexpr? If the content CURL* points to is evaluated at run-time, you can't use it in a compile-time function, as the compiler cannot evaluate it. So., remove the constexpr from your lambda.